# Django: Actions that provide intermediate pages ... with 100k rows

Tags: django, django-admin

I know how to write Actions that provide intermediate pages, since the docs are great:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages

But, if my selection contains 100k rows, the pattern of the docs does not work since the URL gets too long.

How to write Django Admin Actions that provide intermediate pages and can handle +100k rows?

Comment: Can't you persist the ids somewhere else, e.g. the session or a database table?

Comment: @Alasdair yes, I could persist the IDs in cache or DB. But writing 100k IDs is a lot of overhead. Would be nice if you could store just the QuerySet SELECT-statement without all IDs.

Comment: Your best bet would in this case would be to use Post the data. But your can't post through a redirect. So you need to write a auto submit template and pass the data. Instead of doing a `return HttpResponseRedirect("/export/?ct=%s&ids=%s" % (ct.pk, ",".join(selected)))` you will render a template and that will auto submit the data to the next url

Comment: @TarunLalwani your solution sound good. But I am missing one part: How to create the queryset from the GET data? This needs to work for list_filter and the nice `date_hierarchy` filter.

Comment: You will have the queryset in `def export_as_json(modeladmin, request, queryset):`, you extract the ids out it and pass it on to the template using variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it this way:

- [Pickle QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets)
- Store pickled QuerySet in the cache under a random ID
- forward the random ID to the next page
- the next pages use the random ID to read the QuerySet from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

When i need something closer to that i used some grouping variables like: `all`, `active`, `accepted`, `denied`. By doing this grouping i can do some bulk action on huge large of data without creating a python list with thousands of pks.

Another good point to pay atention is that you need to pass that to the DB, otherwise you will have a enormous bottleneck on the views/models.